# How to Handle Multiple Image Uploads in ASP.NET MVC Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to upload multiple images to a .NET MVC website. When the images come into the server, I resize them, save information to the database, and then save the actual image on the server in a folder. When I upload them one at a time this works, but if I do multiple uploads at once, I get this error every few uploads:

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

Googling this seems that this is a generic error when you are unable to save a file as some other process is using the location. I assume that the multiple uploads are trying to save in the same folder at the same time and one dies. They are not the same filename.

How can I avoid this? Is there a way to have the threads wait for one to finish before it tries saving in the same folder? I'm wondering if there is a method that is like the await call where it waits until it can save.

**Edit More Code**

I can't copy my whole function as it's very long etc but the part that saves is the following:

```
//Now we will try saving the actual file. Generate the file name.
String savedFileName = PhotoTools.GenerateImageFileName(photo.image_base_file_name);
String thumbnailSavedFileName = PhotoTools.GenerateImageFileName(photo.image_base_file_name, true);

//Store the file path (directory) that we are going to save the image to.
String directoryToSave = Server.MapPath(Constants.ImageDirectory + $"/{house_id}");

//Create the directory. This function will not do anything if it already exists.
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToSave);

//Save the images to the filesystem.
mainImage.Save(Path.Combine(directoryToSave, savedFileName), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
thumbnailImage.Save(Path.Combine(directoryToSave, thumbnailSavedFileName), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

They should not be the same filename as the file name is created as such:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates the base property image filename based on the passed in information.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propName">The house name that we will use for the file name.</param>        
/// <returns>The generated file name.</returns>
public static String GenerateBaseImageFileName(String propName)
{
    //Save the current datetime to create the filename with.
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    //Generate the name.
    return $"{CommonTools.RemoveSpecialCharacters(propName).Replace(" ","-")}-{now.Hour}{now.Second}{now.Millisecond}";
}
```

Comment: Do these images being saved in the same folder have the same file name? You will have to provide some code to accompany your question with regards to how you're saving this data.

Comment: @DanielShillcock Added some code.

Comment: try using `lock` to the function/code with file I/O operations

Comment: @YvetteColomb I supposed there could be an interruption. In terms of how I handle the connection and threads....not sure. Dropzone handles itself sending all the files to me, and all the code I didn't show in the question is just business logic code that is standard c#. I don't do anything specific about threads or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error A generic error `occurred in GDI+` mean that the file or the path doesn't exist:

so try for example to check if the directory exist or create it if not .. and then double check if you have already a file with same name or if the full path exist:

try:

```
var guid = Guid.New().ToString(); //<-- generate new random guid

//Store the file path (directory) that we are going to save the image to.
String directoryToSave = Server.MapPath(Constants.ImageDirectory + $"/{house_id}");

//Create the directory. This function will not do anything if it already exists.
if(!Directory.Exist(directoryToSave)
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToSave);

//Save the images to the filesystem.
mainImage.Save(Path.Combine(directoryToSave, savedFileName + "_" + guid), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Hope it helps you